# Evaluating the mean of complex Gaussian RV numerically.

Tags: probability, integration, contour-integration

Let $Z$ be a Circularly-symmetric non-central complex Gaussian random variable; thus, $Z \sim CN(\mu,1)$ with covariance between the real and imaginary part $C = 0$. According to the wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution), the mean of $Z$ $E[Z] = \mu$ and the pdf of $Z$:
$f_{Z}(z) = \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-|z-\mu|^2}$
Now I want to evaluate $E[Z]$ numerically as:
\begin{equation}
E[Z] = \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-|z-\mu|^2} z dz 
\end{equation}
I have tried to evaluate this integral numerically using contour integral, which requires a finite region. As the region, I choose a huge square in the complex plane. To be more exact I choose $\mu = 10$ and the region as 1000x1000 square centered at the origin of the complex plane. When I evaluate this contour integral on MATLAB, the answer is zero. I would understand if it was slightly off as we don't cover the whole plane I would understand but getting zero indicates that I am doing a mistake in my formulation.

I want to note that I don't have a degree in math or I am not a math student, so my understanding of contour integrals (maybe I should say integrating over complex plain in general) might be off.